# Updating Python on Raspberry Pi3b

Tags: updates, python, raspberrypi

Set up a new Raspberry Pi and followed the instructions in this articel to update to the current version of python: https://raspberrytips.com/install-latest-python-raspberry-pi/

When attempting to change the symbol link for python though I am running into an error that says

```
ASMLS-FlowMez@ASMLS-FlowMez:/usr/bin $ sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.11 python 
ln: failed to create symbolic link 'python3.11': File exists
```

I look into the folder on the given path and I do not see the python3.11 files there but apparently it exists.

Comment: which OS version?  You also appear to be linking to `python` which is python2, could potentially break things.

Comment: That article is about Raspberry Pi OS, not Ubuntu.